# MacTeX 2020 Not Installing memoir.sty?

Tags: luatex, memoir, mactex

I've recently started a new MacTeX/TeXShop/LaTeX project after an interval of 6 or 7 years away from it all. I thought for my new project I would use the memoir package in conjunction with the subfiles package and with LuaLaTeX.

The problem is that when I go to typeset my .tex file that the TeXShop console says

> ! LaTeX Error: File `memoir.sty' not
>   found

When I run TeX Live Utility app it tells me that memoir is installed, but when I do a find I don't see memoir.sty:

```
$ cd /
$ find . -name "*memoir.sty" -print
./usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-patch-memoir.sty
./usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-memoir.sty
./usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/simurgh/simurgh-memoir.sty
```

Is this a known problem with MacTex or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you type `kpsewhich memoir.cls` at a command prompt?

Answer (score 8):

`memoir` is a documentclass, not a package. So you load it like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
```

not

```
\usepackage{memoir}
```

Comment: Thanks, Alan. My problem was that I was doing both.
It is a bit confusing, though. In Section 3 of The Unofficial Guide to LaTeX2e (dated 2018) the author (not yourself) says that the only classes built into LaTeX are: article, book, letter, report, and slides, and that "Many other document classes are available as separate packages..."

Comment: Unfortunately a very poor choice of words. :)